# Counters and their "partners"

Tags: counters, latex-base

A counter created via `\newcounter{<counter>}` is stored internally as `\c@<counter>`, just like a reference made using `\label{<label>}` is stored internally using `\r@<label>`. What's the use of `\cl@<counter>` and `\p@<counter>`? The macros associated with their use include (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\@definecounter#1{\expandafter\newcount\csname c@#1\endcsname
     \setcounter{#1}\z@
     \global\expandafter\let\csname cl@#1\endcsname\@empty
     \@addtoreset{#1}{@ckpt}%
     \global\expandafter\let\csname p@#1\endcsname\@empty
     \expandafter
     \gdef\csname the#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter
          {\expandafter\@arabic\csname c@#1\endcsname}}
%...
\def\refstepcounter#1{\stepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel
       {\csname p@#1\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname}%
}
%...
\def\stepcounter#1{%
  \addtocounter{#1}\@ne
  \begingroup
    \let\@elt\@stpelt
    \csname cl@#1\endcsname
  \endgroup}
%...
\def\@addtoreset#1#2{\expandafter\@cons\csname cl@#2\endcsname {{#1}}}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is given by [the LaTeX source documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf):

> **`\p@foo`** Macro that expands to a printed ‘reference prefix’ of counter
>   foo. Any `\ref` to a value created by counter foo will produce the
>   expansion of `\p@foo\thefoo` when the `\label` command is executed. See
>   file `ltxref.dtx` for an extension of this mechanism.
>
> **`\cl@foo`** List of
>   counters to be reset when foo stepped. Has format
>   `\@elt{countera}\@elt{counterb}\@elt{counterc}`.

For instance,

```
\newcounter{subsubsection}[subsection]
```

calls

```
\@newctr{subsubsection}[subsection]
```

and this is defined as

```
\def\@newctr#1[#2]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#2}{\@nocounterr{#2}}{\@addtoreset{#1}{#2}}}
```

So the counter `subsection` is automatically reset when `\subsubsection` is called, hence `\cl@subsubsection` contains `\@elt{subsection}`.

As the documentation says, the `p@` feature can be used to "extend" the label of a counter. For instance, `article.cls` contains

```
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\theenumi(\theenumii)}
\renewcommand\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}
```

with the effect that

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item foo 
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item bar
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{itembaz} baz
    \end{enumerate}

  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\ref{itembaz}

\end{document}
```

will result in

[image: p@ example]

and not just "i".

Comment: @lockstep that was copied verbatim from `article.cls` ;-)

Comment: Nobody ever claimed that class was perfect. ;-)

Comment: This mechanism is slightly broken by default in latex. See here: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=labelformat Also, you must have had a bug in your grep commandline because I see that this feature is used in various babel language files (eg, hebrew.ldf) also in the ams classes (amsart et al) and many others.

Comment: @LevBishop Thank you for pointing that out! As I said, I just grepped for " p@" (note the space), so it is more than likely I overlooked something. The string "p@", though, is so frequent (think of "strip@", "skip@" or simply `\p@`) that it is futile to grep everywhere for it :-) My conclusion was that *I* can't give examples. If *you* can, please do! (Anyway, I'll try to find something based on your hints and incorporate that in my answer).

Comment: The \p@ mechanism is mainly used for nested lists, see article.cls `\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ha! I **knew** I had seen it used somewhere! I had been looking in the area of sections all the time! I'll update my answer now.