# Pause framenumber

Tags: beamer, counters

I have some slides in Beamer and I would like to stop the counter of the number of slides at some point: in the example below, instead of getting 1/5, 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 5/5, I would like to have 1/3, 1/3, 2/3, 2/3, 2/3, 3/3. Thank you very much

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\begin{beamercolorbox}{author in head/foot}
\usebeamerfont{authorinhead/foot}
\vskip2pt \hskip5pt \insertsection \hfill
(\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber) 
\hskip3pt
\end{beamercolorbox}
}
\newcommand{\Blue}{\color[rgb]{0,0,1}}
\newcommand{\beginbackup}{
   \newcounter{framenumbervorappendix}
   \setcounter{framenumbervorappendix}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
   \addtocounter{framenumbervorappendix}{-\value{framenumber}}
   \addtocounter{framenumber}{\value{framenumbervorappendix}} 
}

%--------------------------------------------------------------

\title{Model}
\author{}
\vfill
\date{Today}

%--------------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\beginbackup
\begin{frame}

\titlepage

\end{frame}

\backupend
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Motivation and preview of the model}
\begin{itemize}
\item bla
\item bla2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Example}
\begin{itemize}
\item bla
\item bla2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Example}
\begin{itemize}
\item bla3
\item bla4
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Example}
\begin{itemize}
\item bla4
\item bla5
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Conclusions}
\begin{itemize}
\item ble
\item ble1
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What is the second number after `/` supposed to be? The total number of frames?

Comment: By default, `beamer` doesn't include a counter so I'm not entirely clear about your question. You might be adding a counter and want that to appear to be stopped? Or you might be thinking of something else? (Obviously the real counter `beamer` uses can't stop - otherwise the slides would all end up with identical content, I think.)

Comment: @cfr: I think, it's about the `framenumber` counter

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear, which counter is meant, but I assume the `framenumber` counter.

I use the `assoccnt` package (still experimental, but available on TeXLive/CTAN, see [Associated counters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195762/associate-counters-stepping-many-counters-simultaneously) ) to get an associated counter `totalframenumber`, always increased with `framenumber` which is a driver counter then and then use the `\SuspendCounters{framenumber,totalframenumber}` command to stop the counting for those two counters. Driver counters can only suspended if the package option `globalsuspend=true` is used.

After 3 slides (as in the OP), `\ResumeSuspendedCounters` is used to revoke the suspension.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[globalsuspend=true]{assoccnt}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\newcounter{totalframenumber}%
\newcounter{totalframetrigger}%
\DeclareAssociatedCounters{framenumber}{totalframenumber}%

\renewcommand{\theframenumber}{\arabic{framenumber}/\arabic{totalframetrigger}}%

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\setcounter{totalframetrigger}{\number\value{totalframenumber}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{This is frame number \theframenumber}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{This is frame number \theframenumber}
\blindtext
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{This is frame number \theframenumber}
\blindtext
\end{frame}

\SuspendCounters{framenumber,totalframenumber}%
\begin{frame}{This is frame number \theframenumber}
\blindtext
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{This is frame number \theframenumber}
\blindtext[2]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{This is frame number \theframenumber}
\blindtext
\end{frame}

\ResumeSuspendedCounters
\begin{frame}{This is frame number \theframenumber}
\blindtext
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```

There is the 2nd and the 3rd frames with 'id' `3/4` shown in the screen shot, however, the text is too large for the left frame (see left image)

[image]